Merge [SRP-6] into [SRP]
At the moment we have two tags for secure remote protocol (SRP):

srp (12 questions)
srp-6 (15 questions)

I suggest merging srp-6 into the more general srp.

To avoid cluttering the front page even more (if that's possible), I'd prefer a moderator merging the tags, instead of having to retag all of them.

Should we make [tag:srp-6] a synonym of [tag:srp] or just merge them (then [tag:srp-6] will have no questions and should dissappear, but would come back if anyone added it again)?

I'd first attempt it without a synonym, but if it gets added back too often, we can add one. The current [srp-6] tag is older than [srp], so its existence doesn't show that people will add it if [srp] already exists.

I merged srp-6 into srp. The srp-6 is now gone. We'll see if it creeps back in.
